# Looping through a java.util.List and populating java.util.Map

Tags: java, list, loops, dictionary

There is a class 'Category':

```
public class Category
{
private Integer id;
private String name;
private Category parentCategory;
...
//getters and setters
}
```

and then, there is `java.util.List<Category> categories` that is a list of Category instances. As you can see one category object can be a parent to other categories (categories and subcategories concept).
I would like to loop through this list and create a map that consists of (categoryObject, list of child categories to categoryObject). How can i implement this loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
    final Map<Category,List<Category>> map = new HashMap<>();
    for (Category cat : categories) {
        if (cat.parentCategory == null) continue;
        List<Category> children = map.get(cat.parentCategory);
        if (children == null) {
            children = new ArrayList<>();
            map.put(cat.parentCategory, children);
        }
        children.add(cat);
    }
```

But I would use a set instead of a list. Or even better: guava's multimap.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this, don't have a compiler near me so their might be a compiler error or two, but something close to this should work.

```
Map<Category, List<Category> > myMap = new HashMap<Category, List<Category> >();

for (Category cat : categories) {
    if (cat.parentCategory != null) {
        List<Category> myList;
        if (myMap.get(cat.parentCategory) == null) {
            myList = new ArrayList<Category>();
        } else {
            myList = myMap.get(cat.parentCategory);
        }
        myList.add(cat);
        myMap.put(cat.parentCategory, myList);
    }
}
```